# C# Populating listbox with byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, listbox, byte, fill

```
private void sendBCode()
    {
            NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            outStream = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("0000|ORD|SUPP");

            serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
            serverStream.Flush();

 /*No issues so far, I am sending a data stream in the code above. Now I need 
 to return data:*/

            byte[] inStream = new byte[1500];
            var count = serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, inStream.Length);
            string returndata = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream, 0, count);

 /*The data I am returning looks like: "0000|ORD|SUPPS|MWH|GGR|MBS" , I need to
   split this data and populate a listBox with it, as you can see below, I can split
   the returned data.*/

            string[] s = null;
            clsConn.prdType PRD = new clsConn.prdType();
            s = returndata.Split('|');

             aaaa = s[1];
             bbbb = s[2]; //etc...
     }
```

The number of spitted values are undetermined, but I want to fill a listbox with every item returned. How would I do that?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
But what if I want to populate the listBox the same way but excluding the first three items?

Comment: you can use string.Join functions and string.Split to create text streams and listbox addrange function to add range of items

Comment: Based on the code I posted above, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can a range of items by `AddRange` in listbox
Do that like this code:

```
 NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
        outStream = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("0000|ORD|SUPP");

        serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
        serverStream.Flush();

        /*No issues so far, I am sending a data stream in the code above. Now I need 
        to return data:*/

        byte[] inStream = new byte[1500];
        var count = serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, inStream.Length);
        string returndata = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream, 0, count);

        /*The data I am returning looks like: "0000|ORD|SUPPS|MWH|GGR|MBS" , I need to
          split this data and populate a listBox with it, as you can see below, I can split
          the returned data.*/

        string[] s = null;
        clsConn.prdType PRD = new clsConn.prdType();
        s = returndata.Split('|');

        aaaa = s[1];
        bbbb = s[2]; //etc...
        //Excluding First three items

        string[] s_copy = new string[s.Length - 3] ;
        Array.Copy(s, 3, s_copy, 0, s.Length - 3);

        ///-------
        listBox1.Items.AddRange(s_copy);
```

Comment: you can use array.copy and copy values to new array and populate it!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't konw if i understand you just need to use `AddRange` with `Windows Forms`

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string[] s = null;
    clsConn.prdType PRD = new clsConn.prdType();
     s = returndata.Split('|');

    listBox1.Items.AddRange(s);
}
```